# Unity HDRP shadows on terrain are too dark

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow, unity3d-terrain

[image: [1]:]

Other shadows are good, but shadows on terrain too dark

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to go into your directional light and alter the shadows there? See my screenshot. Click the gear with the plus icon and you can alter tint. Please let me know if this helps you. I know it's a bit hidden but this could be the fix! Let me know of your settings in Volume if it doesn't work.

[image]